# How to know an object's type?

Tags: javascript

I have scanned through related questions here but couldn't find a satisfactory answer on how to determine the type of a JavaScript object.

In fact, the `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)` technique used below is something I got from one of the threads here. However, it seems not to do the job.

**Scenario 1:**

```
var Person = function(name)
{
    this.name = name;
};

var joe = new Person("Joe Bloggs");

console.log(typeof joe); // prints object

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(joe)); // still prints [object Object]
```

**Question:** How do I get it to print `Person`?

---

**Scenario 2:**

```
var Person = function(...) { };
var Cat = function() { };

var joe = new Person(...);
var polly = new Cat(...);
```

**Question:** How do I distinguish between the two objects based on their types? `console.log(typeof obj)` or `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj))` on either of them will yield the same result.

**`instanceof`**

I am aware of `instanceof` but that's not a swiss army knife. It is tedious in that it can only be applied for testing whether or not an object is of a certain type. How do I get to know the type of an object?

Comment: You can use [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) or the `constructor` property directly. Other than that, i don't think javascript is typed well enough to meet your expectations...

Comment: There’s also `joe && joe.constructor` to get the constructor function. And if you declared your function like `function Person(personName){`…`}`, you can also use `joe && joe.constructor && joe.constructor.name` to get `"Person"`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Yes, I am aware of that. In fact, I have another related question on `instanceof` which I will soon be posting. But that isn't a swiss knife.

Comment: Those objects have the same type, `object`.

Comment: Why do you want to know the type? It's not usually the right thing to do.

Comment: @melpomene Be that as it may, it is pertinent to know what ctor they came from, nevertheless.

Comment: @EngineerDollery: I don't know as of now. I am just learning JavaScript and following my intuition. Coming from a strongly-typed / statically typed language, it just feels intuitive to want to know.

Comment: You can get the constructor with `obj.constructor`.

Comment: There are several typed languages that compile into javascript, e.g. [typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), but even there you only have static type-checking from the compiler. As it emits javascript in the end, the same issues arise when you want to confirm something run-time. It still helps a lot though imho.

Comment: 'not strongly typed' basically means that type information is lost at runtime, leaving behind just objects and a handful of primitives. You can't really use javascript as if it were java -- the patterns are different. To a large extent, modern javascript is primarily functional anyway. I think you're not going to find a way to do this satisfactorily.

Comment: Thank you both, Engineer Dollery and ASDF Gerte. I understand your sentiments and agree with them. I also am aware of TypeScript, ScriptSharp and a few others (SomethingBridge), Babel, CoffeeScript and a whole lot of transpilers. I just want to learn JavaScript for once.

Comment: Thank you, @Xufox and melpomene. That kind of helps a bit. I am not sure how to then check for object type equality on the basis of what that outputs. However, as indicated by others' comments, perhaps type equality has little significance in a dynamically typed language such as JavaScript.

Comment: @Xufox tested a while ago in Chrome and FF - Chrome will also set the name "Person" of the constructor if you assign nameless function to a variable (both function Person() {} and var Person = function() {} work in Chrome)

Comment: Excellent info. on typeof https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/

Comment: @Novice Thanks for sharing. Seems like a long read. Will read it tomorrow for sure.